# With a list of columns, filter a data frame with at least one of the columns meeting a condition?

Tags: python, pandas, filter

Say that I have a dataframe with 50 columns. Of these 50 columns, I have a list of 6 columns that are of interest.

```
list_cols = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

I want to filter the dataframe such that at least one of these 6 cols must be <= 5. How would I go about doing this without having to tediously write something like:

```
df.loc[(df['a'] <= 5) | 
       (df['b'] <= 5) |
       (df['c'] <= 5) |
       (df['d'] <= 5) |
       (df['e'] <= 5) |
       (df['f'] <= 5)]
```

Or writing a for loop on each column, concatenating, and dropping duplicate rows? Is there another option? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just using `any`

```
df[df[list_cols].le(5).any(1)]
```

Comment: I knew there was something simple. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Wouldn't it print all the columns?? as the inner condition only passes a boolean mask on indexes to df[]

Comment: @hacker315 he need all columns just need filter the row

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `min`

```
df[df[list_col].min(axis=1).le(5)]
```

Comment: Wouldn't it print all the columns?? as the inner condition only passes a boolean mask on indexes to df[]

Comment: @hacker315 that seems to be what OP wants with `loc`.